# Sync state on different pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, state

I am creating a app like reddit for practice:

I have a `ListView` of `PostWidget` and you can click on a "Comments" button on the `PostWidget` to go see the comments on that post. On the comments screen you can see a preview of the post, which is basically a `PostWidget` with the same contents and key(ValueKey, instance isnt the same but the value passed to it is.)". You can bookmark and like the post both on the `Posts` screen and the `Comments` screen but the problem is that the state of the `PostWidget` is not synced between the two screens. As it stands, if i like a post on the `Comments Screen` and then go back, that post's state would not have been updated because neither the `initState()` nor the `build()` gets called.

I would be ok with sharing some snippets, but i honestly don't know what to show for this question.

Comment: You have to implement state management [check documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). If you have already some code and you need help, post it here.

Comment: @PeterKoltai i know how to do state management, but what i want to know is a way to force that single widget to call either `build()` or `initState()` when i press the back key

Comment: The reason is, i am not sure how good of a idea it is to store potentially 1000s of posts with quite a bit of data in state. There are also different tabs which will show different posts and it will get messy if i were to store those posts and get them everytime.

I will do it if there is no other way.

Comment: I think you can't force `build()` or state update, it is managed by the framework.

Comment: How do you load and store this data?

Comment: currently each `Post Screen` (there are multiple) is retrieving the data from the server, parsing it, storing in a `List<>` and showing it to Posts Screen. When going to Comments Screen i just pass the Post to the screen.

Comment: And you also store somewhere which user likes which posts, and load that as well?

Comment: That is handled in the server, Since i dont need to know which user liked what in the app, only how many liked it.

Comment: I still think that the proper way in Flutter is handling your post list with `ChangeNotifier` above `Post`, and use this in both `Post` and `Comments` screen.